# Android, RX: what put to UI thread - collections or elements?

Tags: android, rx-java

Suppose there is an observable, which generates sequences of very large (10,000+ elements) Collection. This observable works on background thread, then passes result to UI thread, where RecyclerView adapter adds each of the strings.
In general, there are two approaches, where to split each of lists on separate strings:

1. In observable itself (emit not collections, but strings), on worker thread.
2. In Subscriber, on UI thread.

In first case UI makes a little job. It is significant for application **responsiveness**
But due of **overhead** to transfer each of string between threads, overall time of processing data may also significantly growth, downgrading application performance.

What do you think, which approach you would prefer?

**Example code.**

Approach 1, processing data on background thread:

`Observable.create(subscriber -> {
        // Data is transferred from background to UI thread 10,000 times.
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            subscriber.onNext("String " + i);
    })
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .subscribe(data -> 
        RecyclerView.Adapter adapter  = ...;
        // UI holds for processing just one string.
        adapter.add(data);
    });`

Approach 2, processing data on UI thread:

`Observable.create(subscriber -> {
        Collection<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) data.add("String " + i);
        // Data transfers from background to UI thread only once
        subscriber.onNext(data);
    })
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .subscribe(data -> {
        RecyclerView.Adapter adapter  = ...;
        // Long operation, UI waits until all 10,000 element will be processed.
        for (String e : data)
            adapter.add(e);
    });`

Comment: I'm not sure what the two different approaches look like. Can you add some code? I usually just have my Subscriber take in a List<Object>, call adapter.swapItems(list), which notifies that the dataset has changed and repopulates the recyclerview, which is I believe what your option 2 does.

I'm not sure what you're imagining for option 1.

Comment: Added come code for example.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO I'll take a third approach.

```
stringsObservable.buffer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread)
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread)
  .subscribe(adapter::addAll)
```

The reason to buffer is that is you add items that fast you will make the recyclerView fail.
The time for the buffer, or to use simpler buffer(nItems) it's something to be tuned.

Answer (score 0):

Just test and decide what actually works better for you (as usual, when we speaking of performance). I advice you not to limit yourself with the two variants. Consider also intermediate variants passing to adapter blocks of 10-100 strings.